# Installation of ROS imu_tools Package

Tags: package, ros

I am trying to install imu_tools package into rosdep in ubuntu. After I set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, it says "Missing Resources cmake_modules". Does that mean I have to get the directory of cmake and include it in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Is there anything else that I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<your_ros_distro>-cmake-modules
```

solved it for me